# Missed to file Schedule B with 2016 Tax return for foreign bank account

Tags: taxes, income-tax, form-1040x, fbar, amended-tax-return

I e-filed my 2016 tax return few days ago, but for my foreign accounts missed to file Schedule B (the tax software generated only 1040EZ). I have correctly reported the interest income of foreign accounts on tax return by converting to USD.

I am about to file FBAR and while researching for that found out now that I had to file Schedule B also (for Part III) with the tax return. I do have to file FBAR because in 2016 my total combined value of foreign accounts was more than $10,000.

What should I do now ? Should I file amended tax return(same income amounts as original return) and attach Schedule B with Part III filled to it ? Will the IRS view this negatively ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can file an [amended tax return](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Taxes-101/How-to-File-an-Amended-Return-With-the-IRS/INF14402.html) (form 1040X) and include the additional files.

> The Internal Revenue Service (IRS) knows the tax code is complex, and
>   that people make mistakes.

It will not be viewed negatively on you. It would be worst if you found out you made a mistake and did not attempt to correct it.

Comment: Assuming you used software (including over the web) to prepare the original return, usually that same software can prepare the amended return and you only need to enter the (very small) changed item(s), but you can't _efile_ 1040X, you must print it out and physically mail it.